# Telnet ignores raw bytes

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons-net

I am trying to develop a java application that reads raw data from a telnet client. I use `TelnetClient` from [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) to communicate and read-write to the device.

My device (a thermohygrometer) sends raw bytes that need to be parsed to get the actual measurements. I am able to communicate with the device but the problem is that while reading binary data it ignores some bytes. Specifically it ignores 0xff and 1 byte before it.

I tested with the telnet client from terminal but I have the same behavior as from within the app.

The first image show the wireshark capture while the second the raw input from telnet. (Right after multiple 0x00 is the problem!)

[image: Wireshark Capture]

[image: Telnet Capture]

I understand like 0xff is an escape character or a special command. Is there anyway I can change it so It will treat it as binary data instead of trying to interpret it?

Comment: So just to clarify, it doesn't sound like the device is actually using the telnet protocol... why not just make a raw socket connection with it?

Comment: I was reading the device manual saying that it uses a _telnet like_ communication protocol and I thought it was telnet. I tried with a `Socket` and it worked fine. Thank you!